# Then or Than? Which one is correct?

Tags: time

which is the correct one?

```
If not, then that e-mail wasn't personally from me.
```

or:

```
If not, than that e-mail wasn't personally from me.
```

Comment: You might consider posting this on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com).

Comment: _Than_ occurs only in comparisons -- _`A` is more `X` than `B` -- or something with the same meaning, like _prefer_. So if there's no comparison, use _then_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use "than" when relating two or more things. Use "then" otherwise.

> The dog is *bigger* **than** the cat.
>
> Birds are *smarter* **than** spiders.
>
> I went to the store, **then** I went to the library.
>
> If you don't like the guy, **then** don't vote for him.

So to answer your question, the correct one is:

> If not, then that e-mail wasn't personally from me.

Answer (score -1):

Here's the answer: use *then*
Your sentence is simply an "if...then". So the key here is the "if".

And that's really all there is to it!